# common numbers function of two arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays, numbers

Need help with common numbers function 
function takes the two input arrays and their size (which 
is same for the given problem) and counts how many common numbers are there between the two arrays and returns this count. This is what I have now.

```
int common_numbers(int ar[],int ra[],int x)
{
        int i;
        int j;
        int a;
        for (i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<x;j++)
            {

                if(ar[i]==ra[j])
                {
                     a++;
                }

            }
         }
        printf("%d",ra[j]);
        printf("%d",ar[i]);
         return a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You failed to initialize the counter:

```
int a = 0;
```

Without that your code invokes undefined behaviour (UB).

And the two `printf` calls need to be removed because they access beyond the end of the arrays. They also invoke UB.